# German student visa extension

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, germany, study, visa-extensions

I am Indian and my German visa expires on 16th May, 2017 but I need to travel to India between 14th April and 30th of May. Even if I apply for extension before I leave, I don't think I will receive it on time.
I hold a German student visa.

Are there any other options to hasten the process or to obtain a temporary visa for three months or so?